# Clementine seed results

Tags: fruit-trees, seeds, citrus, pollination

I've got 7 plants from clementine seeds and want to know what possible results I can expect in terms of fruiting if any, depending on which different citrus trees could have pollinated the parent.
The seeds come from fruits probably grown in spain

What is likeliest to have pollinated my seeds and will it produce fruits? That's what I'm most interested in.

Comment: Greeting @user20820 and welcome to G&L. Please take the Tour https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tour and look at 'How to ask' https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask because your question is flagged for closing as too broad. Adding more information/details to your question would help others to give specific answer.

Comment: Welcome from me too! Thanks for taking the time to go to the [help], and for editing the question. A few more details would be helpful, which you can edit in. Where do you live? How old are the trees?  Have they ever borne fruit? I'm not a tree person, but we have experts here. They might ask you more questions, not because you're doing a bad job, just because it's the best way to help you. If you ever have problems understanding the site, just leave a note and someone will respond. We hope you'll stay here and have fun!

Comment: Are you planning on planting the trees outdoors or keeping them in containers?

Comment: Thank you guys, they'll stay in containers, but i'm interested in their viability for producing fruit independent of their locale and what fruit would come of. Thanks

Comment: Very closely related: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/19359/will-i-get-lemons-from-a-tree-grown-from-a-lemon-seed/ 

Strictly speaking, my answer there is also the same answer to this.

Comment: @GardenerJ. There you've written definitly get fruit, you think thats the case here?

Comment: @user20820 I would very much expect fruit. No idea what it will taste like, could be sweet, could be more sour than a lemon.

Answer (score 3):

There is no sensible answer to your question I'm afraid because clementines do not come true from seed, as I'm sure you're aware; there is no way of knowing what has pollinated them, so it's a lottery. You may get very large trees that don't produce any fruit, or trees that do produce fruit after ten years or so but not anything you might consider eating, or, you might just get something edible. If you have the room to plant in the ground, it will be an interesting experiment, though you will have to wait probably around ten years to find out what they will produce. Most commercially sold citrus fruits are from trees that have been grown from vegetative cuttings.

Comment: Most commercial citrus trees are also grafted onto rootstock (similar with Apples). Apparently it is also possible to reduce the time to fruiting (ie. less than 10 years) if you use a rootstock.